# Power function works wrong

Tags: c, function, math.h

```
printf("%d",pow(5,3))
```

it's printing 0, and works fine when number is different from 5 why?

Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: `pow()` takes in `double` and returns `double`

Comment: `pow()` returns a double, use `%f` or `%lf`. Check out [The C Library Reference Guide](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of the power function is double. using the double conversion specifier to prints the output of power function.

the conversion specifier for double is not "%d". It should be "%f".

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
printf("%f",pow(5,3));
```

Since return type of `pow` is `double`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use %lf or %f:

```
 printf("%lf",pow(5,3));
```

As pow function returns double.